# Rails View: Accessing text field elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am a newbie to Ruby on Rails. And I am working on a project. In my view, I am asking the user to input some data using `text_field_tag`. I know you can access the data entered in the controller using `params[]`. But how do I access the value the user has entered in a different  part of the same view? I tried searching but I was not able to obtain an answer.

Comment: what do you mean "has entered in a different part of the same view"? Is this about subform or just different form?

Comment: Say the user has to enter his name, then I want to display the name the user has entered somewhere else in that form. Also, I want to check that the name the user entered is the same name that is in a table in my database. I tried doing this using a function in my controller but then it renders a new page and my requirement is that I must stay on the same page.

Comment: 1. Display the name a user enters somewhere else on the page > Do this with JavaScript, 2. Check if name exists in database and stay on the same page > Call a controller action via XHR (Ajax), check if name exists in database via Ruby and return the result to the client. If you use jQuery then have a look at http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/.

Answer (score 0):

You can call params system all of your view like in your controller so you can use it.

```
<%= params[:my_params] %>
```

Comment: I don't want to submit a form because I am not putting the data entered by the user into the database. Can i use the above code in my view without using forms?

Comment: if you want use value define your user without submit form and do on "live" you need do it on Javascript. Not in Rails.

Comment: When using Javascript, I need to compare the value the user entered with a value in the database. So I attempted to use Javascript in my view and ruby to access my database. But how do I compare a rails instance variable with a javascript variable? I tried many ways from all the different websites but none of them worked.